# Suppressing verbose console output - SwiftUI / MacOS Monterey

Tags: swiftui, macos-monterey

Is there anyway to suppress the very verbose console output I am getting with MacOS Monterey and SwiftUI code? Here's a snippet of the output:

```
2021-07-20 09:58:18.267602+0100 BBCFTEST[19341:1880374] IMKInputSession (deactivate) CFRunLoopObserver kCFRunLoopExit (State change BEGIN) - innerRunLoopCount=1, otherInnerRunLoopDetected=0
2021-07-20 09:58:18.267637+0100 BBCFTEST[19341:1880374] IMKInputSession (deactivate) CFRunLoopObserver kCFRunLoopExit (State change END) - innerRunLoopCount=0, otherInnerRunLoopDetected=0
2021-07-20 09:58:18.270063+0100 BBCFTEST[19341:1880374] IMKInputSession (deactivate) CFRunLoopRunInMode exited, (kCFRunLoopRunStopped)
2021-07-20 09:58:18.270109+0100 BBCFTEST[19341:1880374] IMKInputSession (deactivate) CFRunLoopRunInMode (kIMKXPCPrivateRunLoopMode) ] RunLoopFinished(1)/Stopped(2) - Run result = 2, (Invocation already done = 1) (Sentinel IsZombie = 0)
2021-07-20 09:58:18.270147+0100 BBCFTEST[19341:1880374] IMKInputSession (deactivate) CFRunLoopRunInMode() LOOP DONE!
```

Comment: I should add this is with Xcode Version 13.0 beta 3 (13A5192j)

Comment: then same on my Version 12.5.1 (12E507)